# How to prove that from any point lying outside a given line one can drop a perpendicular to this line, and that such perpendicular is unique?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry

Given a line AB and arbitrary point M outside this line, how to prove that one can drop a perpendicular to AB, and that such perpendicular is unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $MC$ and $MD$ be two distinct perpendiculars, i.e. $m\angle{MCA}=m\angle{MDA}=90°$. Then, according to the corresponding angles theorem, $MC$ is parallel to $MD$. But parallel lines do not have common points (point $M$ belongs to both lines). Contradiction.

Comment: Great, but what about the first part of the proof? To drop a perpendicular.

Comment: OK, to prove that there is at least one perpendicular we can use axiom that it's always possible to draw a circle with any center and distance. Let's draw a circle with $M$ as the center and radius equal to distance between $M$ and $AB$.  Then we connect $M$ with the point of intersection of $AB$ and the circle. According to tangent radius theorem it will be a perpendicular.

Answer (score 0):

Let $MC$ and $MD$ be two perpendiculars.

Thus, if $C$ and $D$ are different points

we get that a sum of measures angles of $\Delta MCD$ greater than $180^{\circ}$,

which is contradiction.

Comment: Invoking the theorem on the sum of angles of a triangle makes use of the fifth postulate, which is not necessary here (see Vasya's answer).

Comment: @Aretino I think  theorems about sum angles of triangle and about parallel lines are the same things, but if you say...

Comment: The theorem stating that two lines forming equal corresponding (or alternate) angles are parallel can be proved with [Euclid's exterior angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_angle_theorem), which doesn't rely on fifth postulate. This postulate is needed to prove the converse theorem (that two parallel lines form equal alternate angles).